# Cross browser text-shadow

Tags: css

I'm looking for a way to get text-shadow that looks like css3 text-shadow, but that works with IE, Firefox, Opera, Safari , etc... The solutions I found either looked messed up or did not look consistent in IE. Thanks

http://www.workingwith.me.uk/articles/css/cross-browser-drop-shadows

```
.shadow {
    height: 1em;
    filter: Shadow(Color=#666666,   
            Direction=135, 
            Strength=5);
}
```

This doesnt work for me... in IE

```
ul.dropdown a.selected-l {
    background-image: url('Images/Navigation/Left_round/hoverL.png');
    height: 50px;
    width: 130px;
    font-family: Cambria, Cochin, Georgia, Times, "Times New Roman", serif;
    font-size: large;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: none;
    line-height: 50px;
    vertical-align: middle;

/* pretty browsers*/
        text-shadow:#000 0px 0px 5px;
        /* ugly ie */
        zoom:1;/*force hasLayout*/
        position:relative;/*for absolute position of child element*/

;


}

ul.dropdown a.selected-l span {

    position:absolute;
        left:-7px;top:-7px; /* strength + pixelradius */
        z-index:-1;/* force under the normal text */
        /* the magic: filters */
        filter:
            progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Glow(Color=#eeeeee,Strength=2)
            progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.blur(pixelradius=5, enabled='true')
        ;
        zoom:1;/*force hasLayout*/

}
```

Comment: What are the solutions you found so far? Care to share?

Comment: Please specify a range of IEs.  What if only the latest IE were supported?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

My suggestion will be to use [CSS3 text-shadow](http://www.css3.info/preview/text-shadow/) (for Webkit-based browsers, FF3.5, Opera 9.5).

For IE, use IE conditional comments to implement one of the followings:

- [sIFR](http://fortysevenmedia.com/blog/archives/sifr_3_hard_drop_shadows/)
- [cufon](http://wiki.github.com/sorccu/cufon/styling)
- [FLIR](http://facelift.mawhorter.net/examples/) (not too sure about shadow effect)
- [IE-DXImageTransform](http://kilianvalkhof.com/2008/design/almost-cross-browser-text-shadow/)

Some related articles:

- [Cufon vs sIFR vs FLIR](http://thinkclay.com/technology/cufon-sifr-flir)
- [SO - sIFR or FLIR?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/386483/)
- [SO - SIFR vs Cufon vs Typeface.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/692990/)

Comment: Yea, I can't think of an ideal solution.

Answer (score 0):

Check out this post i wrote about this problem:

[Crossbrowser Text Shadow with Jquery](http://byme.se/jquery/crossbrowser-text-shadow-with-jquery.html)

Maybe that's more up your alley? It *IS* using jQuery though and isn't a really über efficient way.. but anyway it's something. :)